# Issue with BOOL method

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following method to check if an email already exists in my database:

```
-(BOOL) emailHasBeenTaken:(NSString *)email
{



        PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
        [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:email];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && objects.count>0) {
                NSLog(@"in the emailHasbeenTaken EMAIL IS DUPLICATE");
                [self duplicateEmail];

            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"in the emailHasBeenTaken, EMAIL IS NOT EXISTENT");
            }
        }];

    return YES;

}
```

The problem that I am having is that sometimes it will work and sometimes it wont, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, what I mean by working or not is this... I check when a new user is trying to sign up with the following code:

```
     if (![self emailHasBeenTaken:self.emailTF.text]) {
    // EMAIL WAS NOT FOUND IN DATABASE SO IT WILL ASSIGN THE 
       TEXTFIELD VALUES TO USER PROPERTIES     

    email = self.emailTF.text;
                    user.email = email;
                } else
                {
                    [self duplicateEmail];
                    return;
                }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I find myself adding the `!` to my if statement to get the desired result.. Is there a way to receive multiple returns from a `BOOL` statement? i.e. one case would return YES and the other would return NO.

Comment: @matt, I tried that but i keep getting a build failed error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are making an asynchronous call to Parse which does nothing (except for calling the `duplicateEmail` method, which you have not posted so I have no idea what that does) and then you are always returning `YES` from your `emailHasBeenTaken:` method.

Since you need to make an asynchronous call to fetch any users that have that email taken, you need to reformat how your method works. You'll want to change it to something like this:

```
- (void)emailHasBeenTaken:(NSString *)email completion:(void(^)(BOOL emailIsTaken, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    void (^completionCopy)(BOOL, NSError *) = [completionBlock copy];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:email];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"in the emailHasbeenTaken ERROR HAS OCCURRED");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, error);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (objects.count > 0) {
            NSLog(@"in the emailHasbeenTaken EMAIL IS DUPLICATE");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(YES, nil);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"in the emailHasBeenTaken, EMAIL IS NOT EXISTENT");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, nil);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Note that this method is now asynchronous itself, so using it as a condition in an `if` statement is not possible. You would instead use it like this:

```
NSString *emailFromTextField = self.emailTF.text;

[self emailHasBeenTaken:emailFromTextField completion:^(BOOL emailIsTaken, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // TODO: handle any errors here
        return;
    }

    if (!emailIsTaken) {
        // Assuming "email" and "user" are instance variables here:
        email = emailFromTextField;
        user.email = email;
    }
    else {
        [self duplicateEmail];
    }
}];
```

Comment: can you please explain with a little more detail, all my `duplicateEmail` method is doing is just showing an alert in my view

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer with what I think you should be doing instead.

Comment: I tried adding your code but I get a build error "Too many arguments to block call, expected 1, have 2"

Answer (score 3):

You are always returning `YES`.